# BorderLayout with GWT

Tags: html, gwt, border-layout

How to achieve a true BorderLayout effect in GWT?

If possible without a library?
If I need to use a library, please not a payed one, neither a deprecated one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Kinjal's post, the 2.0 [`*LayoutPanel` classes](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels#LayoutPanels) are almost certainly what you want. The `DockLayoutPanel` and its subclass the `SplitLayoutPanel` will provide this functionality in two different ways.

There are two important things about using Layout Panel classes. First, use a strict doctype (such as the html5 doctype). Second, all panels must be given a size and must be informed of resizes - this is why they all implement the `RequiresResize` interface.

The easiest way to do that is to start not with a `RootPanel`, but with a `RootLayoutPanel` - this will ensure that you get resize events from the browser window. Then, add in the layout panel of your choice, and it too will be resized.

If you build your own widget subclasses and want to be notified when resizing happens, you too should implement `RequiresResize`. Similarly, if you are building a widget subclass that will be sizing its children, you should implement the `ProvidesResize` interface.

Answer (score -1):

Use `HLayout` or `VLayout` and set custom css style to achieve it.

You can also take a look at this [Layout documentation](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels#LayoutPanels)